# How to get my results to add up correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small script that checks for selected boxes and ads them up.
Some boxes are worth two some are worth one.
I can get them to add up, but only if I select one of two pointers first or vice versa.

Html

```
<div class="checkbox pmmargin">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="one">Some blah blah text</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox pmmargin">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="two">Text</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox pmmargin">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="one">text</label>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
$(".two").change(function() {
    var classes = $("input[type='checkbox'].two:checked").map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().length * 2;
            document.getElementById("program_management2").innerHTML = " Score:" + " " + Math.floor(classes) ;

    $(".one").change(function() {
    var classes2 = $("input[type='checkbox'].one:checked").map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().length;

            document.getElementById("program_management").innerHTML = " Score:" + " " + Math.floor(classes2 + classes) ;

});  
    });
```

Comment: you want the answer in JQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Why not $(".one").change outside of $(".two").change?

Comment: What's the use of map(function() {return this.className;}).get() ?

Comment: It doesnt matter if its jquery or java script.. zfrisch and mm759 not sure how to and honestly mm759 i just hacked it together from one that was kinda close to what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to add the value of each checked checkbox, you should use the `value` attribute.

Since the value is a string, you have to parse it to an integer to use it in an addition.

```js
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
     var result = 0;
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
          result += parseInt($(this).val());
     });
        $("#total").html(result);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <input type="checkbox" value="1">This box value is 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2">This box value is 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="5">This box value is 5<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    The checked total is: <span id="total">0</span>
```

**EDIT**

I added a "checked class" count.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    var result = 0;
    var classOne = 0;
    var classTwo = 0;

    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
        result += parseInt($(this).val());
        if( $(this).hasClass("one") ){
            classOne++;
        }
        if( $(this).hasClass("two") ){
            classTwo++;
        }
        $("#totalOne").html(classOne);
        $("#totalTwo").html(classTwo);

    });
    $("#total").html(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="one">This box value is 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="two">This box value is 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="one">This box value is 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="two">This box value is 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="two">This box value is 2<br>
<br>
<br>
The checked total value is: <span id="total">0</span><br>
Class "one" checked total : <span id="totalOne">0</span><br>
Class "two" checked total : <span id="totalTwo">0</span><br>
```

Comment: Patrice This is really close to what i want however I need to be able to get it by class and i can set the class to a number rather then value as i need to be able to send the values back in to ruby so i can save them in a session that has a bunch of other stuff stored in it as well

Comment: Thank you very much